# Leaflet: draw polyline across dateline without using worldCopyJump

Tags: javascript, leaflet

1. I need to show marker across map, drag sideway will have the marker show without hiding the previous one

   - `worldCopyJump` will replicate but previous map marker will be gone
2. I need to limit maxbound only to top and bottom, not sideway.
   I couldnt use code below:

   ```
   var maxSouthWest = L.latLng(-85, -360);
   var maxNorthEast = L.latLng(85, 360); 
   var maxBounds = L.latLngBounds(maxSouthWest, maxNorthEast);
   ```
3. Can the `latitude` and `longitude` to be correct even crossing map dateline?
4. I need to draw shortest polyline route which similar to `google map`, example `Japan` to `USA`

   - in my leaflet will have the longitude more than 180 (240 example), which i want it to be in correct lat lng
   - `worldCopyJump` doesnt suit what I need
   - cannot cut polyline as user are allow to draw the best route line (even wrapping the whole world)

Refer to https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/5340 for image.